# passing parameters to an image when using the run button in docker desktop dashboard

Tags: docker, docker-desktop

I normally use the command line when using docker (I have since the beginning), but I wanted to give docker desktop dashboard a try. I'm trying to build an image into a container via the dashboard's `RUN` button. I see that when I do that, the GUI gives me an option for `optional settings` but under that section, there isn't a place to add parameters like you would on the command line (example: if I'm running docker mysql image I can pass parameters/arguments on the command line like: `docker run --name some-mysql -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=my-secret-pw -d mysql:tag`).

is there a way to do that in docker desktop dashboard?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: Interested in this as well, currently stuck on figuring this out.

Comment: Anyone figured this out, yet?  It appears that one would lose parameters like --net, --link if you restart a container in Docker Desktop, that was originally "run" from command line. Only port and environment variables seem to be retained between restarts.

Answer (score 0):

This should be fixed by now:

[image: Docker Desktop Run image]

You can choose some settings as option via dropdown. Keep in mind that this is thought of as a "just works" kinda approach, meaning further settings in regards to networking and the like are not shown.